# Can we start using this stackexchange to ask questions related to Salesforce Commerce Cloud?

Tags: e-commerce, commerce-cloud

With the recent acquisition of Demandware and the rebranding process to Salesforce Cloud can we start using this stackexchange to ask questions related to Salesforce Commerce Cloud?

Comment: I think this is a meta topic. And I suggest yes.

Comment: Yes, Exacttarget is one of the example.  ( Can this question migrate to Meta?)